# Display all worksheets in list checkbox and multi print worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple sheets and would like to be able to click a "print" button which in turn opens a dialog where I can check mark multiple sheets and click "ok" which will print the selected sheets. I've been looking thru the site and found similar cases but nothing exactly like this question.  Currently my code will only print one blank page:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectSheets()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim TopPos As Integer
    Dim SheetCount As Integer
    Dim PrintDlg As DialogSheet
    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Check for protected workbook
    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure Then
        MsgBox "Workbook is protected.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

'   Add a temporary dialog sheet
    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set PrintDlg = ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets.Add

    SheetCount = 0

'   Add the checkboxes

    TopPos = 40
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
'       Skip empty sheets and hidden sheets
        If Application.CountA(CurrentSheet.Cells) <> 0 And _
            CurrentSheet.Visible Then
            SheetCount = SheetCount + 1
            PrintDlg.CheckBoxes.Add 78, TopPos, 150, 16.5
                PrintDlg.CheckBoxes(SheetCount).Text = _
                    CurrentSheet.Name
            TopPos = TopPos + 13
        End If
    Next i

'   Move the OK and Cancel buttons
    PrintDlg.Buttons.Left = 240

'   Set dialog height, width, and caption
    With PrintDlg.DialogFrame
        .Height = Application.Max _
            (68, PrintDlg.DialogFrame.Top + TopPos - 34)
        .Width = 230
        .Caption = "Select sheets to print"

    End With

'   Change tab order of OK and Cancel buttons
'   so the 1st option button will have the focus
    PrintDlg.Buttons("Button 2").BringToFront
    PrintDlg.Buttons("Button 3").BringToFront

'   Display the dialog box
    CurrentSheet.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If SheetCount <> 0 Then
        If PrintDlg.Show Then
            For Each cb In PrintDlg.CheckBoxes
                If cb.Value = xlOn Then
                    Worksheets(cb.Caption).Select Replace:=False
                End If
            Next cb
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=1
            ActiveSheet.Select

        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "All worksheets are empty."
    End If

'   Delete temporary dialog sheet (without a warning)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    PrintDlg.Delete

'   Reactivate original sheet
    CurrentSheet.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up my mess Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your interpretation of `SelectedSheets` is causing the problem. By iterating through worksheets and selecting specified worksheets does not add those worksheets to the `SelectedSheets` collection. The simplest way would be to print sheet by sheet on each iteration of the loop.

So this part of your code would become:

```
        For Each cb In PrintDlg.CheckBoxes
            If cb.Value = xlOn Then
                Worksheets(cb.Caption).PrintOut copies:=1
            End If
        Next cb
```

Comment: OUTSTANDING! Thank you! 98% closer than what I could find! Although I'm still getting one blank page at the end even when I select three check boxes, the 3 sheets print but followed by one blank page